# Storing source code of current browser in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to get the source code(HTML code) of the current browser through a chrome extension. I was trying to store this HTML code in a string, but it doesn't seem to work.

http://jsfiddle.net/ufbxge08/2/

```
<head>
<style>
  button {
    height: 30px;
    width: 100px;
    outline: none;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<button id="bth1">Predict</button>
<script src="popup.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
<form>
  <label id = 'mybtn1'></label>
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
btn1.onclick = function scrapeThePage() {
// Keep this function isolated - it can only call methods you set up in content scripts
var htmlCode = document.documentElement.outerHTML;
var btn = document.getElementById("mybtn1");
btn.innerHTML = htmlCode;
console.log(htmlCode)
```

}

I expected the code to store the source code in a string but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to show HTML code inside an HTML element you may need to set the text content (`innerText`), not the HTML content (`innerHTML`):

```
bth1.onclick = function scrapeThePage() {
    // Keep this function isolated - it can only call methods you set up in content scripts
    var htmlCode = document.documentElement.outerHTML;
    var btn = document.getElementById("mybtn1");
    btn.innerText = htmlCode;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1jk94r50/

Comment: Oh, awesome. Thank you. Will mark as answer in 2 minutes

Comment: `innerText` performs [additional processing](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#the-innertext-idl-attribute:dom-innertext-3) like converting newlines to `<br>` so it's slow and in 99.9% of cases you'd be better off using `textContent`.